# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.2.1 and autorest 3.0.6187 returns has no servers entry

Tags: swagger, openapi, autorest, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am having trouble generating a csharp or powershell client for a very basic Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.2.1 site with autorest 3.0.6187
Is there another combination of the software versions that does work together or is there a way to make the json output include servers information with the location of the api in it?

```
PS C:\projects\MySwagger\scripts> autorest --input-file=http://myswagger.api.local/swagger/v1/swagger.json --powershell --output-folder=CSharp_MySwagger --namespace=MySwaggerNamespace --v3
AutoRest code generation utility [cli version: 3.0.6187; node: v10.14.1, max-memory: 8192 gb]
(C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation.
https://aka.ms/autorest
   Loading AutoRest core      'C:\Users\MySwagger\.autorest\@autorest_core@3.0.6262\node_modules\@autorest\core\dist' (3.0.6262)
   Loading AutoRest extension '@autorest/powershell' (~2.1.327->2.1.372)
   Loading AutoRest extension '@autorest/remodeler' (~2.1.0->2.1.27)
FATAL: Error: Operation http-operation:0 : /api/EventItems has no servers entry (Are you missing 'host' or 'servers' information in your source file?)
  Error: Plugin remodeler reported failure.
```